# Using HttpURLConnection or URLConnection with https domains

Tags: android, https, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I'm using `HttpURLConnection` and `URLConnection` to connect to some domains on my apps to download configurations, images, etc...

Now, I must switch all the domains to https (because IOS needs it). Should my code on Android using `HttpURLConnection` and `URLConnection` work with the new https domains or it is mandatory to migrate the source code to be compatible with https domains?

Answer (score 2):

When you open a https URL, a HttpsURLConnection is returned which extends HttpURLConnection. Your code should work fine, but consider handling SSL Exceptions.

Comment: why should i consider handling SSL exceptions? what do you mean? thanks.

Comment: A SSLException extends IOException and it is thrown, if the server behind your https URL does not provide a valid SSL certificate, i.e. one that is accepted by the TrustManager (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/TrustManager.html). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLException.html

Comment: Maybe you want to post a notification like "Secure connection could not be established." I assume your handling IOExceptions, so I think you don't have to change anything, the Subclass SSLException just tells you, why the connection failed.